# Why is this console2 question put on hold as off topic when other console2 questions are not?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Console2 opening in tiny winow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642090/console2-opening-in-tiny-window?noredirect=1#comment43863003_27642090) Perhaps it's the title. Maybe my description. But this question got a lot of heat for being off topic.  I see many other questions about console2 and as I point out, there is even a valid console2 tag, but this question was deemed by most as off topic.  I don't understand and frankly was taken back by how rude and callous the users commenting on it were.

I typically turn to posting questions on Stack Overflow as a last resort. 99% of the time I find the answers that I need from questions that have already been asked.  I just can't help but feel a little jaded after my experience with this one question.  Rather than suggestions about how I could write my question better, or asking if I could provide more details, I got nothing but flaming from other users.  Is that typical here?

Comment: As there seems no actual programming going around -- only tinkering with user settings --, to me this suggests this more of an End User type question than related to programming. Not *everything* about software is automatically "good for Stack Overflow".

Comment: I restored a couple of the comments on that question, by the way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are in a very murky grey area. That is, questions about tools "commonly used" by programmers are considered OK, but questions about "general software" are off-topic.

That is, asking about Visual Studio is clearly on-topic, but MS Word is not. A console is very much between these two extremes, as a console isn't *exactly* a programming tool.

That said, a tag existing does not mean a question is on-topic (we burninate tags all the time), and old questions existing also doesn't mean that its ok today (the standards are different). Also, even a question being about a valid tag doesn't mean the question itself is on-topic/high quality.

Only moderators can see the deleted comments on your post, but you should not have been treated rudely, no matter what. Users that did that were in the wrong (and thats probably why their comments were deleted).

Should you have been "flamed" (if that indeed occurred)? No. However, I can see the point of view that your question was unsalvageable because it wasn't at all on-topic. Expecting "edit" type comments to such a question is probably an unreasonable expectation.

Comment: You make some very good points.  I suppose my problem was my over reaching expectations that I had about stack overflow.  This was partly due to the history I have had with using stack overflow and finding almost every answer I ever needed. Perhaps those expectations were unfair.The site is defined by a users guidelines (which I will admit I have not read to its fullest), but to play devil's advocate here, this sites reputation is based on historical records.  So it's kind of a tough pill to swallow when its said that the previous topics, questions and answers dont define current expectations

Comment: @JakeS Not sure which expectation you were referring to, but SO is definitely *not* for any question about computers. Super User is the SE site for general computer questions. You may want to read the [help/on-topic] for more information about the kinds of questions that are on-topic here. Finally, this site *has* a good reputation because we keep our quality high and the site clean of off-topic posts. In the past, when there were less users (and less other SE sites) people could get away with more. That model simply isn't sustainable today.

Comment: I didn't meant to imply that it was for every question about computers. Since Console2 was a tool that I was introduced to specifically for development and because I had seen other topics, questions and answers here on this site regarding it, it seemed appropriate. I had not realized that Console2 feel into that gray area that found it off topic. I understand now and thank those who took the time to help me sort that out. And the expectation I was referring to was the one that I had created from my experience (of reading old posts) and not of reading the help center. That was my error.

Comment: @JakeS No problem. One other thing to note. Glancing over the other questions in that tag (especially the recent ones), they seem to be about *programming* Console2 to do something or working with the program in a programming context. Just reporting a bug with the program is a different kind of question entirely. Thanks for being so receptive to what the community has to say!