# Why is my question off-topic while this other question is not?

Tags: discussion, scope

The question I posted to SO is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400610/simulate-exclusive-read-access-to-file-non-programatically).

If it's offtopic as was decreed by the voters, **then how is [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator) not offtopic?**

Neither question expects the solution to use programming, both are about tools that are exclusively useful to software developers.

I've seen lots of other tool-related questions too, that are not getting closed.

[This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281505/122687) clearly says that questions about programming tools are fine.

Comment: Did you have a look at the other questions date? Policies have changed since then.

Comment: That question was posted in October 2009. Rules have changed quite a bit since then.

Comment: Oh, and Robocopy is *exclusively useful to software developers*? Since when?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Not robocopy - *the tool I'm looking for* is exclusively useful to them. That is, the tool that read-locks a file.

Comment: Ok that question is a breeding ground for [self promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator#comment63440197_1554099)

Comment: @Stefan, well, it's even worse then. It looks like you're asking us to provide a *non-programmatical* solution, i.e. an existing tool, to solve your issue. Such questions are called "recommendation questions" and are explicitly off-topic here. In other words, regardless of the interpretation, I'm afraid you lose, and that question is not salvageable.

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring the other question, your is a plain and simple recommendation question. One could argue there are programming solutions to your problem, but you explicitly and in bold exclude those as valid solutions. With that you have created a question which is off-topic, and which would have been off-topic for many years now.

Why you specifically ask about the other, fairly different, question I don't really understand. But while I would agree it's not the greatest of questions, at least it seems to request a solution to problems faced with tools exclusive to software development. It's not asking for any alternative tool recommendations or anything of the sort.

Comment: "tools *exclusive* to software development" [\[citation needed\]](http://www.bluestacks.com/)

Comment: Sssst @Braiam, I just managed to convince them here that playing Pokemon on my desktop was part of the "software development process". Don't ruin this for me.